# The best way to use Cache API in Java for newbies

Tags: java, caching, jcache

I have a small application in java that gets the data from external api. To make it faster. I want to use a caching API. But whether I use JCache or Ehcache I get the same error

```
hzinstance_jcache_shared [dev] [4.2.2] Exception during initial connection to [127.0.0.1]:5703: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.io.IOException: Connection refused to address /127.0.0.1:5703
```

I'm newbie in the caching so I don't know exactly what is required e.g. consfiguration file, etc. My project is just simple Maven project, I don't use Spring yet. Is that a problem for that?
Is there any cache api in java that doesn't require running application on specific ip adress and specific port?

My current code:

```
CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();  
        CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager();   
        MutableConfiguration<Long, String> configuration =
            new MutableConfiguration<Long, String>()  
                .setTypes(Long.class, String.class)   
                .setStoreByValue(false)   
                .setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(Duration.ONE_MINUTE));  
        Cache<Long, String> cache = cacheManager.createCache("jCache", configuration); 
        cache.put(1L, "one"); 
        String value = cache.get(1L); 
        System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your setup? Is Ehcache running on the same machine? How do you know you have the correct port?

Comment: It's basic setup for that using. Unfortunetely, the project is a part of internal work, so I'm not allowed to publish it. But I add my just basic cache code in above.

Comment: All I can tell from this is that something is wrong with setting up the connection between your application and Ehcache.  Make sure all of that is configured properly on both sides.